# php/mysql/ajax: Displaying Query Results In Page With Submitted Form

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, mysqli

I have a form that I'd like to use to populate a where list within a select statement. That part is working properly. However, I'd like to submit the form with AJAX and then have the results appear below in the "peers" div. I took a stab at that but it doesn't appear to be doing anything. Thanks!
HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>990 Report Builder Demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();

  } );   
  </script>

    <script>
      $(function () {

        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'search.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              $('#peers').html(response);
            }
          });

        });

      });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Entity Filter</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Total Entities (EIN Count):";
$sql_ein_count = "SELECT COUNT(EIN) as total FROM filing";
$result_ein_count = $conn->query($sql_ein_count);

        if ($result_ein_count->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result_ein_count->fetch_assoc()) {
        $total = $row["total"];
        echo number_format($total);
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo "<form><table><tr><td>Filing Year:</td><td><select name='year'>";
$sql_years = "SELECT YEAR(TaxPeriod) as year, COUNT(EIN) as total FROM filing GROUP BY YEAR(TaxPeriod)";
$result_years = $conn->query($sql_years);

if ($result_years->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result_years->fetch_assoc()) {
        $year = $row["year"];    
        echo '<option value="'.$year.'">'.$year.'</option>';
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo "</select></td></tr>";
echo '<tr><td>Operating Revenue:</td><td> <select name="revcut"><option value="xs">0 - $499,999</option><option value="sm">$500,000-$2,499,999</option><option value="med">$2,500,000-$4,999,999</option><option value="lg">$5,000,000-$24,999,999</option><option value="xl">$25,000,000+</option></select></tr>';
echo '<tr><td>Keyword:</td><td> <input type="text" size="30" name="keyword"></td></tr></table><button type="submit">Find Peers</button></form>';

$conn->close();

echo "Filtered Entity Count: ";
        echo '<div id="entCount">count</div>';
?>
           </p>
  </div>
<h3>Peer Selection</h3>
  <div id="peers">

  </div>
  <h3>Results</h3>
  <div>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Financial Metrics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Executive Compensation</a></li>
        </ul>
   <div id="tabs-1">
    Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
    Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
    ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis
    lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
    Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
    Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
    ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis
    lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$year=$_POST['year'];
$keyword=$_POST['keyword'];
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql_big_selects = "SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1";
$conn->query($sql_big_selects);
$sql_ent_list = "SELECT OrganizationName AS OrgName FROM header h JOIN filing f on h.FilerEIN=f.EIN WHERE OrganizationName LIKE '%".$keyword."%' AND TaxYr=".$year;
echo $sql_ent_list;
$result_ent_list = $conn->query($sql_ent_list);

        if ($result_ent_list->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result_ent_list->fetch_assoc()) {
        $peer = $row["OrgName"];
        echo $peer;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Since posting this, I created some indexes that make the SQL_BIG_SELECTS query unnecessary. This doesn't affect the problem at hand.

Comment: "doesn't appear to be doing anything". have you checked your browser's console and network tab to see if the request was sent and what the response was? status code and message of the response would be useful info

Comment: also i just noticed `success: function ()` needs to be `success: function (response)` - you forgot to define the parameter for the callback

Comment: Sure, here's my error: POST http://example.com/990/search.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery-1.12.4.js:10254
ajax @ jquery-1.12.4.js:9738
(anonymous) @ index.php:26
dispatch @ jquery-1.12.4.js:5226
elemData.handle @ jquery-1.12.4.js:4878

Comment: I went to search.php and changed it to just display the query instead of executing. It displays the query (in the DIV I want it to), and the query works fine when executed on phpMyAdmin.

Comment: internal server error means something went wrong on the php side which made it crash. i notice you echo each $peer directly to the output inside the loop. try just appending them to a single string an doing one single echo of that string after the loop ends. Not sure what effect a gradual output like that has in an ajax context. The conventional approach is to build the response and output it all at once at the end as I've suggested. Don't know if that's definitely the issue but try it and see